# Find the sum of a non-geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Find the sum of the series or show that the series is divergent.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^n-2}{7^n}$$

So, I've established that this series is convergent via the comparison method; however, I'm unable to find the sum.  I can't seem to find the ratio, so I'm assuming it's a non-geometric series.  I tried finding a pattern by expanding the series, but have not come to any conclusions.  Below you can see my expansion.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{7})^n - (\frac{2}{7^n}) = (-1) + (\frac{5}{7} - \frac{2}{7}) + (\frac{25}{49} - \frac{2}{49}) + (\frac{125}{343} - \frac{2}{343}) + ...$$

This is the beginning of my calc 2 course, so the scope of my knowledge is limited.  Thank you for taking the time to read this problem.  I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you know $\sum \left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^n$ and $\sum \frac{2}{7^n}$ converge. Then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^n -2}{7^n} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{7^n}.
$$
Can you proceed from this?

Comment: Thanks for helping out choco_addicted!  Actually, seeing it written out like that clears everything up!

Comment: Got $$\frac{7}{6}$$

Comment: @JoeyJ That is a correct answer. [Wolframalpha here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(5%5En-2)%2F7%5En+from+0+to+inf)

Comment: awesome! Hope your night is going well :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $|r|<1$, then  we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}$$